# Can wedge and dash bonds on 1, 2 position of cyclohexane ring be used to signify trans orientation of the substituents?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, cyclohexane

I've to make the structural isomers for cyclohexane. On position 1, there's a methane group with wedge bond and on position 2, a methane with dash bond. So I'll have to make the trans isomers only as they are not in the same plane or should I make the cis isomers too?

Or, can wedge and dash bonds on 1, 2 position of cyclohexane ring be used to signify trans orientation of the substituents? Is it actually trans or is it there just to show that the molecules lie in different planes or something?

For reference: as it is the 1,2 position, cis will be axial on 1. equatorial on 2. Trans will be axial on both 1 and 2.

Comment: Related: [Chair conformation. Wedged lines vs no wedged lines?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/43381/7951)

Answer (score 6):

So if you drew a wedge in position 1 and a dash in position 2, it would mean that they are on the same plane - either both axial or both equatorial - assuming that the ring was in a chair conformation.

However, if the objective is to show the structural isomers very clearly, it may be better to use either the chair conformation sketch:

[image: Chair Sketch]

... or the Newman Projection:

[image: Newman Projection]